# Mocking the aws security token services

Tags: mocking

AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard() withCredentials(new AWSStatic CredentialsProvider (new BasicAWSCredentials(cognitoAccessKeyId, cognitoSecretKey)).withRegion(regionStr).build();

I need to mock this line